# Page is keep on loading when play server started

Tags: browser, configuration, playframework-2.1

I want to configure play 2.1.0. I configured successfully and create the new project and i have started play server also. But my problem is when i am trying to load by browser by give url as localhost:9000. Its keep on loading. It is not giving output. If I install 2.2.2 its loading correctly. But 2.1.0 is not working. Please anyone provide solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

do you use for both the same play version? 
When I upgraded to play 2.2.x I needed to ajust the sbt from 0.12 to 0.13.
Probably if you use the correct play version for your 2.1.x application it will work